# HTML5 audio tag - Handling of m3u8 in chrome/firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I'm facing issues with m3u8 playlists on chrome and firefox (edge works like a charm)

I'm trying to send data converted with ffmpeg the line I use for conversion is the following making the m3u8 file at same time:

```
ffmpeg -i .\european-anthem-2012.mp3 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -f segment -segment_time 15 -segment_time_delta 3 -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list playlist_aac.m3u8 outfile_aac-%03d.aac
```

As destination formats I've tried also mp3: `-c:a mp3 -b:a 64k` and vorbis: `-c:a libvorbis -b:a 64k`

the m3u8 file looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:16
#EXTINF:12.004717,
outfile_aac-000.aac
#EXTINF:15.000091,
outfile_aac-001.aac
#EXTINF:15.000091,
outfile_aac-002.aac
#EXTINF:15.000091,
outfile_aac-003.aac
#EXTINF:15.000091,
outfile_aac-004.aac
#EXTINF:15.000091,
outfile_aac-005.aac
#EXTINF:15.000091,
outfile_aac-006.aac
#EXTINF:15.000091,
outfile_aac-007.aac
#EXTINF:10.495420,
outfile_aac-008.aac
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

the file I use is this: [EU Anathem](https://europa.eu/european-union/sites/europaeu/files/docs/body/european-anthem-2012.mp3)

The HTML I use is this:

```
<html>
<audio  id="track2" 
        src="playlist_aac.m3u8" 
        type="audio/x-mpegurl"
        >

    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>

</audio>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('track2').play();">Play</button>

</html>
```

the files (audio pieces, playlist and html) used are in the same local folder as the html page

When I run this code on edge (double clicking the HTML) everything works
on chrome as soon as I click the button the console logs `audiotag.html:61 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources`

On Firefox the error is this: `NotSupportedError: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.`

(Expected behavior is file playing)

Comment: These browsers don't support HLS directly.  You need to use something like HLS.js to load the video in via MediaSource Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Chrome & Firefox does not support Native HLS playback.

You cannot play HLS(.m3u8) directly using audio or video HTML tag.
You have to use an external library to do this for you.
Examples: Hls.js, video.js, shakaplayer.js etc

Safari also does support it btw since it is developed by Apple.

Bonus Content: TV browsers like Samsung (Tizen), LG(WebOS), Hisense also do support native HLS playback.

The external libraries, what they do it, they use MSE API to play HLS content. this is known as MSE-HLS support.
Some libraries like dash.js do not have it. (pls confirm this from documentation)

Hence if you are looking to play HLS content on a browser which does not support native hls playback make sure to use a library which supports MSE-HLS playback.

Comment: video.js can't play mp3 via m3u8.