# Issue using <audio> tag trying to stream m3u8 on Firefox

Tags: html

I have this really simple html:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br>
Test
<audio controls preload>
    <source src="https://stream11.polskieradio.pl/pr1/pr1.sdp/playlist.m3u8" />
</audio>
</body>
```

When I paste this directly into address bar of a browser, I'm getting a suggestion to open this in VLC Player.
My question is simple, is it possible to embed this into `<audio>` tag to be able to play this from a browser?? Because as it is it's just frozen and doesn't play anything...
Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to previous question:
[HTML5 audio tag - Handling of m3u8 in chrome/firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666681/html5-audio-tag-handling-of-m3u8-in-chrome-firefox)
Seems like these browsers don't support HLS directly. You need to use something like HLS.js to load the video in via MediaSource Extensions